# How long a thread wait while other thread accessing synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, thread-synchronization

Threads can wait until other threads release lock which accessing synchronized block. 
I would like to know how long a thread can wait while other thread accessing synchronized block? and when will it come to know that the other thread released lock?

Comment: It can wait forever. That situation is known as deadlock.

Comment: How about non-deadlock threads?

Comment: @Murali: It will keep waiting until the lock is released, which may or may not ever happen.

Comment: Yes, my question is how can it know when the lock is released?

Comment: @Murali When the other thread enters the synchronized block, ie the critical section.

Comment: @Sotirious When a thread is in synchronized block other threads will be pushed into blocked state and how blocked thread come to know it got the turn to execute?

Comment: The exact details how other threads know when when no other thread is inside the synchronized block does not need to concern you - they do know it. Not sure if Java even specifies those details. It just guarantees that threads sleep until the synchronized block is free. And threads are not guaranteed to enter the synchronized block in the same order they start to wait for it. Maybe you find details in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html

Answer (score 1):

If the variable `lock` has been synchronized on in one thread, all other threads attempting to use `lock` to synchronize will be blocked until `lock` is no longer being synchronized on.

```
//all other threads waiting on thread 1...
synchronized(lock)
{
    //thread 1 storing digits of pi into linked list... or whatevs.
}
```

As others have said, threads will wait indefinitely for a variable to become free for synchronization.